# How to fix Cross Site Scripting (XSS)? can we fix using .htaccess

Tags: php, xss

I am not able to fix Cross Site Scripting (XSS) on our site. I am sanitizing the input. Some part of code is as follows

```
$smecompname = $_POST['companyname'];
$companyname = strip_tags(trim($smecompname));
            $companyname = htmlspecialchars($companyname);
            $companyname = $this->validateInput($companyname);

protected function validateInput($data)   {
$data = preg_replace('/[^\p{Arabic}\dA-Za-z0-9 !@#%^&*_.-]/ui', ' ', $data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = html_entity_decode($data);

    return  $data;   }
```

Client is using some kind of testing tools and there comment is Cross Site Scripting (XSS) can happen to site. Please advice what else I can do to fix the issue.

Can we fix the issue using .htaccess file.
 thank you.

Comment: If someone is telling you your site is open to XSS attacks, you should ask them 'how', with proof of such, so you have a better idea where to begin checking and fixing your code.

Comment: There is a field on form company name, as per testing team if they set the input to ()&%<acx><ScRiPt>prompt(985005)</ScRiPt>. there is  alert prompt of 985005 that means its executing script. If we check from url in browser it doesn't happen as client side validations are in place. But when they check through some tools it's getting executed. Please advice

Comment: An input of `()&%<acx><ScRiPt>prompt(985005)</ScRiPt>` would be converted to `&amp %prompt 985005` with that code, which doesn't create a prompt. Where is the variable being output and what html does it produce? You can disable the client-side validation for testing, or make your own post requests, as you can't rely on that for security.

Answer (score 1):

We can leverage filter_input_array (available in PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7.) 
I typically will add this snippet to my SessionController, because all calls go through there before any other controller interacts with the data. In this manner, all user input gets sanitized in 1 central location. *If this is done at the beginning of a project or before your database is poisoned, you shouldn't have any issues at time of output...stops garbage in, garbage out.*

```
/* Prevent XSS input */
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
/* I prefer not to use $_REQUEST...but for those who do: */
$_REQUEST = (array)$_POST + (array)$_GET + (array)$_REQUEST;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php